# Raspberry pi wiringPi c not able to send serial data

Tags: python, c, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I have a working python file for my RaspberryPi which send serial communication

```
import serial           # pyserial
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO)

on_packet = bytearray()

on_packet.append(0x00)
on_packet.append(0xFF)
on_packet.append(0x53)
on_packet.append(0xC3)

while 1:
    ser.write(on_packet)
    sleep(.042)
ser.close()
```

I have installed WiringPi library from
https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi/tree/master/wiringPi
I am using the equivalent in c

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringSerial.h>

int fd;
char on_packet[] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x53, 0xC3};

int main ()
{
  if ((fd = serialOpen("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)) < 0)
  {
    printf("Unable to open serial device\n");
    return 1;
  }

  while(1)
  {
    serialPuts(fd, on_packet);
    delay(42);
  }

  serialClose(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

is this both equivalent .As the c example I provided doesn"t sent the serial output

Comment: I think you should use `serialPutchar` instead of `serialPuts`. Call the former four times, one for each byte you want to send. `serialPuts` will not work because it expects a string, not raw data bytes. As the first byte is zero, it will think it's the end of a null terminated string and return outright.

Comment: I'm confused about `COM3` and `STOPBITS_TWO` in your first example. I believe WiringPi will use 8N1 (only one stop bit). This `COM3` is mapped somehow to a RPI device?

Comment: @JardelLucca serialPutchar solved the issue